# Match any word that starts with a character, Regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, textmate

I am writing an extension for vscode and I am using regular expressions for the grammers. I am currently trying to find every word that beings with * but if there is a solution that expands to any character feel free to suggest it.

Any suggestions so far that I have seen have not worked. I think how TextMatte processes these expressions are a bit different so I think that is why.

Example of what I want.

```
This is a *star word. Here is another *word with a star.
```

```
*start *word
```

Comment: `\*\w+` pcre2: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Tried this before and VScode returns the error "Invalid escape sequence"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(?<!\b)\*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` if you want `*first_name` to be a word

`(?<!\b)\*[a-zA-Z0-9]+` if you don't

Could also throw in other symbols

the `(?<!\b)` is a negative look ahead to avoid stuff like `not*me`

`[a-zA-Z0-9]` is a common way to select all numbers and letters
`+` tells it 1 or more

https://regex101.com/r/epX4R9/1

---

I'm not familiar with `TextMatte` so apologies if this is unhelpful

---

per comments, `TextMatte` accepts the regex from json so the slashes needed to be escaped:
`(?<!\\b)\\*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`

Comment: I use `regex101.com` to test most of my regex

Comment: Problem with all of these is actually a JSON error. You pass the regex as JSON which doesn't like anything that has \ in it.

Comment: can you escape it in json? `(?<!\\b)\\*[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`

Comment: Your a god, the \\ works take a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know of TextMate, escaping characters works as normal, so matching to:

```
\*\w+
```

should give you the words you're looking for, that begin with a *.

Comment: I think you mean `\*\w+` but even so it would (presumably) incorrectly match stuff like `not*starred`

Comment: I did -- thank you, apparently the markup formatting clobbered the initial backslash.  Shows up fine when I'm in edit mode; wouldn't have caught it without your comment. Thanks!
You're also right about my presuming that stars in words wouldn't be of concern to the OP, though the problem description doesn't give any reason why they would be -- can fix that with a lookahead, but those makes the regex *very* slow, so I'd leave it up to the OP to add that in the problem statement if it's an issue.  If it's just "regular" text with certain words starred I'd use mine as posted.